# SD Invoice with amount 0 EUR not to be transmitted to FI

Tags: oop, abap, sap-erp

I am trying to fix a certain already developed function with the goal that the SD Invoice with amount 0 EUR should not be transmitted to FI. As I understood, the below code is used to select the data from FI and SD:

```
* select order-related invoices
    SELECT * FROM vbfa AS v INTO TABLE gt_vbfa_inv
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbak
      WHERE vbelv = gt_vbak-vbeln
        AND vbtyp_n IN ('M', 'O', 'P', '5', '6')
        AND stufe = '00'
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM vbfa
                           WHERE vbelv = v~vbeln
                             AND posnv = v~posnn
                             AND vbtyp_n IN ('N', 'S')
                             AND stufe = '00' ) .
    IF sy-subrc = 0.
* select invoice head status
      SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vbuk APPENDING TABLE gt_vbuk_inv
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbfa_inv
        WHERE vbeln = gt_vbfa_inv-vbeln.                  "#EC CI_SUBRC
    ENDIF.

    SORT gt_vbuk_inv BY vbeln.
    DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM gt_vbuk_inv COMPARING vbeln.

    IF me->gv_items = abap_true AND gt_vbuk_inv IS NOT INITIAL.
      SELECT * FROM vbrp INTO TABLE gt_vbrp
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbuk_inv
        WHERE vbeln = gt_vbuk_inv-vbeln.                  "#EC CI_SUBRC
    ENDIF.
```

As far as I can understand from the above written code, is that the table **VBFA** is used to get the data for FI, while the table **VBRP** is used to get the data for SD. What I want to achieve is that when the invoice number does not have a FI document, then the invoice number will be empty.

If the tables **BKPF**(for the FI) and **VBRK**(for the SD) would be used, then I could have tried the relation:

```
vbrk-xblnr=bkpf-xblnr.
```

However, those tables are not used in the function. May I please ask you, how can I fix the code so that when the invoice number does not have a FI document, thus the invoices with a value of 0 EUR will not generate an FI document, then the invoice number will be empty.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: you wrote a lot of words but the idea is not clear: you wanna block the SD flow when 0 invoice is created from the goods issue? or your function does not create anything and just selects the existing orders/invoices where you wanna filter 0-amount invoices in your custom FM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the goal is

> the SD Invoice with amount 0 EUR should not be transmitted to FI

I suppose your code is in some user-exit or standard program modification when releasing the SD invoice to Accounting. If so, the `BKPF` is not created yet and there's no reason in selecting it.

The select from `VBFA` is not extracting data from FI. Starting from the Sales Order it is extracting the following SD documents (first document flow level only)

```
M   Invoice
N   Invoice Cancellation
P   Debit Memo
5   Intercompany Invoice
6   Intercompany Credit Memo
```

And excluding those invoices that have a subsequent cancellation

```
N   Invoice Cancellation
S   Credit Memo Cancellation
```

Those documents can be found in `VBRK` table (SD invoice header) with the following select

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vbrk APPENDING TABLE gt_vbrk
        FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_vbfa_inv
        WHERE vbeln = gt_vbfa_inv-vbeln.
```

Btw: I don't know the reason for the `VBUK` select since you're not using any document status information

If you're asking for the SD invoices with zero amount with the purpose to not release them to accounting (since otherwise they would produce an error in FI) you don't have to select `BKPF` but check `VBRK-NETWR = 0` for every entry in `gt_vbrk` table